# Global events for Show desktop, show notification center, etc. in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, event-handling

for my program, I need to be able to discriminate between when users are performing some actions using gestures on the trackpad and when using corresponding hotkeys. Typically, I need to know when users show desktop, and if he performed an associated hotkey or associated gesture. Same for switching spaces, etc...
Basically, I have this need for showing notification center, application windows, show desktop, show dashboard,etc... Being able to handle hot corners would even be a plus.

So far I was hoping to be able to investigate global monitors for events, using `NSAnyEventMask` and slightly reverse engineer to figure out what type is the "Mission control open" event, but this was not a success. In fact, `NSAnyEventMask` does not seem to work at all as my method is never called (while it is with other masks such as keydown or mousemove).

I also had a look at the accessibility features, hoping I could add a relevant `AXObserver` notification, but did not find anything neither. I guess this is not surprising since the accessibility API provides a description of *basic* graphical components such as menus, windows, etc... therefore, virtual spaces and notification centers are not described by it.

Finally, `CGevent` tap does not seem to handle these events as when I use the function keys for showing desktop, the only events handled by my `CGeventTaps` are the corresponding keydown and keyup events.

I suspect few possible outcomes.

(1) I have been amazing at trying, but unfortunately this is not possible at all to handle these events ... I seriously doubt this as first I am far from being an amazing programmer, especially in Cocoa, and second, apple prove me that this is possible to access lots of amazing events programmatically and I believe in the power of their API.

(2) I have tried the good methods, but failed because of side factors. It is likely.

(3) other methods could help me to handle these events globally and programmatically (private API?).

Thanks a lot for your help,

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this, but this is caused by an error in Apple's implementation of `NSAnyEventMask`. The docs describe NSAnyEventMask as `0xffffffffU`yet the implementation of NSAnyEventMask is an `NSUIntegerMax` which is `0xffffffffffffffffU`. This is possibly due to the transition from 32 bit to 64 bit computers which changes NSUInteger's from unsigned int's to unsigned long's. Replacing `NSAnyEventMask` with '0xffffffffU' fixes the problem. I've already listed this as a bug to apple in hopes they would fix this.

Comment: Hello @TheAmateurProgrammer, thanks a lot for your reply. I had a quick look and it seems to work. However, the events I am trying to listen to but do not seem to be handled by the global listener... so far, the best option I have found would be to listen to key presses using CGEventTaps and match these events with system preferences to check if the corresponding key (e.g, F3) is associated to a specific command (e.g, show windows). But in that case, I will miss the mouse-based activations (e.g, clicking on notification center icon or using hot corners...) Thanks again.